# Can I connect a SONY NEX-5 to a computer to take pictures?

Tags: sony, tethering, sony-nex, stop-motion

I'd like to get into doing stop motion and have a SONY NEX-5 on my hands. For some reason computer connectability is something I just don't see discussed on the web. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

No, NEX-5 is not supported for remote shooting while tethering with computer.

There are two free software programs from Sony both for Win and Mac, here you can see full list of supported cameras.

1. Remote Camera Control [supported devices](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/imsoft/Win/rcc/us.html)
2. Imaging Edge [supported devices](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/app/imagingedge/en/devices/)

For remote shooting I am using [this IR Remote Controller](http://www.gentles.ltd.uk/gentled/auto.htm), but there are more cheaper options as for example [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00407YLEU)